# How to use np.random.choice on arrays?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

How to use np.random.choice on array ?
I would like the random selection to be of all the array
Together, and not from each array individually.

Thank you

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', usecols=['a','b','c','d'])
df1 = np.array(df.iloc[0:6])
df1
# print(np.random.choice(df1,(5, 4))) # ???

array([['7', '9', '9', '9'],
       ['K', '10', '8', 'A'],
       ['K', '10', '10', 'Q'],
       ['7', 'Q', 'A', '10'],
       ['Q', '10', 'A', 'K'],
       ['9', '9', '7', 'Q']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `print(np.random.choice(df1.values.flatten(),(5, 4)))`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just flatten the array before using `np.random.choice`:

```py
n = 10 # target size
np.random.choice(array.flatten(), size=n)
```

If you'd like to shuffle the array, use [`np.random.shuffle`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) instead.

Comment: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'array' Thank you

Comment: Replace `array` for the name of your variable storing the array.